# Mustache curly braces being moved out of table element within <template> HTML

Tags: html, templates, mustache

The HTML5 `template` element seems to mangle Mustache curly braces in the HTML output, particularly within a `table`:

```
<template id="test">
    <table>
      {{#foo}}
        <tr><td>{{.}}</td></tr>
      {{/foo}}
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    const html = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
</script>
```

The inner HTML shows this:

```
{{#foo}}{{/foo}}<table><tr><td>{{.}}</td></tr></table>
```

However, if instead of a `template` we use a `script` element, the HTML is not mangled:

```
<script id="test" type="text/html">
    <table>
      {{#foo}}
        <tr><td>{{.}}</td></tr>
      {{/foo}}
    </table>
</script>
```

The inner HTML is correct, and can be used by Mustache:

```
<table>{{#foo}}<tr><td>{{.}}</td></tr>{{/foo}}</table>
```

Why is it that this happens with `template`? Is there a way to somehow disable this behavior? Otherwise, apparently, it's not a good idea to use it with a template system like Mustache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<template>` is specifically meant for use with [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components), which has its own templating mechanism that is integrated in the web standards. The HTML inside a `<template>` element should be considered "live" and must be well-formed, so you cannot just insert arbitrary text inside `<table>...</table>` without also wrapping it in `<td>...</td>`.

While a `<script type="not-javascript">` may feel old-fashioned and perhaps a bit makeshift, it is still the only correct way to embed arbitrary template code in an HTML document.

Alternatively, you can save your template in a separate file and import it in your JavaScript modules with the help of a bundling tool and a suitable plugin. For example, if you were to bundle your JavaScript code using Rollup and use Wontache to render your Mustache templates, you could use [rollup-plugin-wontache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-wontache) and structure your code as follows:

*template.mustache*

```
<table>
  {{#foo}}
    <tr><td>{{.}}</td></tr>
  {{/foo}}
</table>
```

*script.js*

```js
import template from './template.mustache';

var htmlCode = template({foo: ['item 1', 'item 2']});
```

There are similar plugins for other combinations of bundling tools and Mustache rendering engines.